optree ImportError when trying to use tensorflow.keras.models
I have installed tensorflow and keras via pip and want to use it, but the following import is failing:
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential #This line fails

The error:
  File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\tree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src.tree.tree_api import assert_same_structure
  File ""...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\tree\tree_api.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: To use Keras, you need to have `optree` installed. Install it via `pip install optree`

I checked that optree is installed, tried to reinstall it but no luck. Does anyone face this issue?
Versions:

Tensforflow 2.16.1
Keras 3.3.3
Optree 0.11.0


Finally, the following commands helped me:
pip uninstall keras
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip cache purge
pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed --user

I have two suggestions of RC:

I firstly installed keras, tensorflow was installed after that
"--user" helped to solve some permission issue


I happened to have the same issue, the solution in my case was to upgrade optree version by
pip install --upgrade optree


Thanks for the suggestion, It didn't help me :(
It shows that I already have the latest version
